# Where is Grub installed?

Tags: grub2

I created a live USB of Ubuntu 16.04 and installed it on another USB drive.

Sometimes, the computer boots into a black screen with grub rescue prompt

```
grub>
```

When  I type exit it takes me to Grub to pick OS.

Why do I sometimes get that and not all the time? When the USB with Ubuntu on it is not even connected, it takes me to this black screen mentioned above before going to Windows.

Is Grub not only installed on Ubuntu USB?

Comment: So you do regularly get the rescue prompt without the USB drive and you don’t when it is connected?

Comment: sorry what ? i get the rescue prompt even if its not connected. Thought grub is just installed on usb. I resetted windows and all full clean. and grub rescue prompt still appears with the ubuntu usb not connected. everything works fine though.

Comment: You have most likely installed Grub to your primary hard drive. Do you want to get rid of it and restore Windows boot loader? Which version of Windows do you use? I’ve used great [instructions for Windows 7](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/) but the process may differ in your version.

Comment: I'm using windows 10 pro. ill check on your instructions. Well I dont mind it to be on my primary drive. I just want to know why it went there, and how i can check if its actually there. When i installed from the live usb pendrive linux, it didnt ask me anything about where to install grub. it only asked me where to put ubuntu. thanks for your replies by the way

Comment: :~$ sudo dd bs=512 count=1 if=/dev/sda 2>/dev/null | strings
t&fh
TCPAu2
r,fh
fSfSfUfh
Invalid partition table
Error loading operating system
Missing operating system
:~$ sudo dd bs=512 count=1 if=/dev/mmcblk 2>/dev/null | strings
:~$ sudo dd bs=512 count=1 if=/dev/mmcblk0 2>/dev/null | strings 
t&fh
TCPAu2
r,fh
fSfSfUfh
Invalid partition table
Error loading operating system
Missing operating system

Comment: Could you edit your question to include your last comment (with proper formatting)? It is very difficult to read. What did you try to accomplish using these commands?

Comment: @Melebius the OP is trying to use the advice in [this link](https://jsosic.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/check-if-grub-is-installed/) in the answer posted by Jemes to see if GRUB is installed. Looks unwise to me!

Comment: Yup if grub is installed on the windows drive.  I would like to check.  Tried a bunch on commands and the bootinfoscript is spouting rubbish that's not even true. Any other suggestions would be amazingly appreciated. Thanks